# jQuery textbox validation using both on keyup and blur

Tags: jquery, validation

I have a textbox and need to validate on both keyup and blur events. If I type in "X", both events will fire and obviously you will see two alerts based on the code below. The keyup event is needed as I may trigger some action based on a valid value and also need keep the blur event in case the Tab key is pressed. The goal is to display one alert here. \m/ \m/

```
$("#txtLength").on('keyup blur', function (e) {
    if ($(this).val().length > 0) {
        switch (true) {

            case !$.isNumeric($(this).val()):
                alert("Please enter a numeric value.");
                $(this).focus();
                break

            case ($(this).val() < 5) || ($(this).val() > 10):
                alert("Length must be a numeric value between 5 and 10.");
                $(this).focus();
                break;

            default:
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: if you do it on `keyup`, you don't need validation on `blur` unless you're doing completely different on `blur`.

Comment: You do need it. If you use only the keyup event, you will get the alert and it will set the focus. However, the user can now Tab off of the textbox leaving an invalid value behind.

Comment: your statement is wrong here. _If I type in "X", both events will fire_ http://jsfiddle.net/EbLdf/ .. Only keyup event gets fired.

Comment: You want to validate on the *ONKEYPRESS* and *ONCHANGE* events.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks for all of your input. Some good ideas helped towards a solution. Sticking to topic from avoiding the display of two alerts using .on keypress and blur, here is what I ended up doing.

```
var bAlertCalled = false;

$("#txtLength").on('keyup blur', function (e) {
    if (bAlertCalled === true) {
        bAlertCalled = false;
        return;
    }

    if ($(this).val().length > 0) {
        var iLength = parseInt($(this).val());

        switch (true) {
            case !$.isNumeric($(this).val()):
                bAlertCalled = true;
                $(this).focus();
                alert("Please enter a numeric value.");
                break

            case (iLength  < 5) || (iLength  > 10):
                bAlertCalled = true;
                $(this).focus();
                alert("Length must be a numeric value between 5 and 10.");
                break;

            default:
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this will only cause a problem if you use alert() or some other method that interrupts the user.  Use a form of inline validation, and the user will likely never notice.  Also, your check of the value did not work, since "6" is not > 5 or < 10.  I fixed that using parseInt:

html:

```
<input type="text" id="txtLength" /> <span id='spanLengthValidation'></span>
```

script

```
$("#txtLength").on('keyup blur', function (e) {
    $("#spanLengthValidation").text("");
    var amt = parseInt($(this).val())
    if ($(this).val().length > 0) {
        switch (true) {
        case !$.isNumeric($(this).val()):
            $("#spanLengthValidation").text("Please enter a numeric value.");
            $(this).focus();
            break;

        case (amt < 5) || (amt > 10):
            $("#spanLengthValidation").text("Length must be a numeric value between 5 and 10.");
            $(this).focus();
            break;

        default:
        }
    }
});
```